# Gson deserialization works strangly

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

Today I discovered some strange behavior Gson. Let's assume we have the following simple JSON

```json
{
    "a": {
        "foo": 123
    }
}
```

With the corresponding classes representation

```kotlin
class A(val foo: Int)

class B(val a: A) {
    val foo = a.foo
}
```

However, notice, that there is a 'shortcut' for `A`'s `foo` in `B`. And the problem is that during GSON deserialization, this field is not initialized. Meaning `assertEquals(123, b.foo)` fails.

Firstly I looked at the generated bytecode, decompiled it, but it looks fine:

```java
 public static final class A {
      private final int foo;

      public final int getFoo() {
         return this.foo;
      }

      public A(int foo) {
         this.foo = foo;
      }
   }

public static final class B {
      private final int foo;
      @NotNull
      private final SubscriptionChangeTest.A a;

      public final int getFoo() {
         return this.foo;
      }

      @NotNull
      public final SubscriptionChangeTest.A getA() {
         return this.a;
      }

      public B(@NotNull SubscriptionChangeTest.A a) {
         Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(a, "a");
         super();
         this.a = a;
         this.foo = this.a.getFoo();
      }
   }
```

The only reason I see is that GSON does not invoke constructor, but rather fills those `final` fields using reflection after the object is created. I will be grateful if you will share your thoughts about it. Thanks in advance.

**P.S** They question is not how to fix it, it is simple (changing B.foo to getter property), but rather why it works the way it does

Comment: Such a design choice guarantees that invoking no constructors and no accessors (hence no imperative code at all) can make a perfect serialization/deserialization round-trip for any object that is serialized/deserialized with `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` (excluding interfaces that do not declare fields and abstract classes that must be extended to "become" instantiable).

Comment: @fluffy but wasn't `Unsafe` made unreachable in recent java versions?  I mean, it may turn out that Gson won't work with Java 11 for example

Comment: Probably. I haven't yet worked with Java 9 and later. If they, the Gson developers, could peek into the future since the very beginning, they might make another design choice. Gson claims to be a Java 6 library, and they don't even have type adapters for Java 8 (Time API, `Optional`, etc) because of that. The only recent thing I'm aware of is that they added some module support to run in Java 9. Anyway, implementing an instance creator would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that indeed Gson does not invoke constructors, but rather create objects using `sun.misc.unsafe`.